# Angular - Add dynamic class at existing classes on host component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this component and I need to add dynamic class at host component dynamically

```
@Component({
 selector: 'test',
 templateUrl: './test.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('className') componentClass: string;

  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.componentClass = this.name ? `test-icons test-icons-${this.name}` : '';
  }

}
```

this works but if I try to add one class on my component this is override by the classes added during control.

Example, if I wtite:

```
 <test-component class="custom-class-i-added" [name]="'icon']></test-component>
```

class "custom-class-i-added" disappear...i want to create a system that add dynamic classes at the existing ones....Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

This should do exactly what you want:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;
  
  // Use input to combine class passed from parent with classes set in component.
  @HostBinding('class') @Input('class') classList: string = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classList = `${this.classList} test-icons test-icons-${this.name}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround You can use [@Attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Attribute) decorator to get component class attribute and then concate with componentClass something like this:

**component.ts**

```
constructor(@Attribute('class') private hostClass: string){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.componentClass = this.name ? `${this.hostClass} test-icons test-icons-${this.name}` : this.hostClass;
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-72pbhv?file=src/app/app.component.css)